# Cannot open file from assets

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code.

```dart
File('assets/i18n/en/strings.xml').readAsString().then((String contents) {
  print(contents);
});
```

strings.xml is located at this path.

in `pubspec.yaml`

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/i18n/en/strings.xml
```

However, I have this error.

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/i18n/en/strings.xml' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

Is there any places I need to check to use `File` class?

Comment: Did you Pub get?

Comment: did you remember to "import 'dart:io';"

Comment: @VidorVistrom +Yushin These suggestions are futile.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. my problem is solved by the Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`AssetBundle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/AssetBundle-class.html) if you want to work with `assets` in Flutter:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

rootBundle.loadString('assets/i18n/en/strings.xml').then((String contents) {
  print(contents);
});
```

If you want to learn more about it, you can follow the [official article on assets in Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#loading-text-assets).

Comment: Thank you !!! The problem is I use assets system in main.dart but I separate d the file. So I forgot to import services.dart in this source code.